# Practicing for an interview, Sorting infinite character stream

Tags: java, stream, character, infinite

So I know how the basics of streams work. Basically I can implement it in java like this

```
inputStream = new FileReader("infinite.txt"); // or socket, whatever

int c;
while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
    //something here
}
```

But this is more of a theory question, and less of a coding question. What is the interviewer looking for when he asks this question? I mean I can use an ArrayList and just use .append each time a string comes in and then run a function to sort it.... each time after I append since you cant say that the ever ends so if you do it after everything is in the ArrayList.

I'm looking for clever solutions, this is a practice interview question.

Hashtables, Trees?

Edit: Keeping in mind Hashtable/Tree usually has a better runtime then a sort on a regular array

Thanks a ton!

Comment: The first thing that jumps into my head is to ask what other constraints they have.  Do they care about constant-time random access?  What are the constraints of my input?  If I'm sorting long random `Strings` I'd answer differently than if I'm sorting a highly constrained set (digits of pi, letters in a book, or anything else with very few buckets).

Comment: What is the question?  "Sorting infinite character stream" is not a question, and "//something here" doesn't say much about what you hope to accomplish.  If the stream really is infinite, then the while loop will never terminate.  In that case, you're going to need at least one other thread for this example to mean anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this, this is the standard for lexical ordering: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort

Comment: But, btw please add the Interview question. This was just the first thing which came in my mind.

Comment: Thanks, This question is actually straight off glassdoor. Real interview is tomorrow. That is why the question may be a little unspecific, sorry about that. Bucket Sort looks great though. First thing that came to my mind was some sort of modified gap/textbuffer strategy but this looks interesting.

Comment: Have you ever considered using a hashtable? Another thought just came to me. The key being the ascii value, the insert would be constant time. And then you can just loop over every possible ascii value (like 150) in the hash table to extract the sorted array.

Comment: For that I need the exact problem. For now i just know, that it is a sorting problem. But consider that hash map insertion and access also gets an impact with hash collisions.

Comment: Yea it would definitely need to incorporate a separate chaining... Idk yea annoying no exact question. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

use
 `private final ConcurrentSkipListSet<Event> eventsInCurrentWindow;`

then you could sort moving window

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(
      new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          System.out.println("new window");
           getToElement().ifPresent(toElement -> {
                 NavigableSet<Event> buffer =         
                 eventsInCurrentWindow.headSet(toElement, true);
                   System.out.println("start publishing: {}    
                     ",ZonedDateTime.now());
                           buffer.forEach(terminateOperation::accept);
                             eventsInCurrentWindow.removeAll(buffer);
                        }
                    );
                }
            },
        5000
    1000
);
```

Wrap string in `Event with Timestamp`, then method `getToElement()` should create element that is last element for current window ( first + 1000 ms )

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the context of the question you could use a Priority Queue

If your "sorted" infinite stream only needs to output sorted data when polled, rather than be completely sorted at any given instance, a priority queue would work. In this case, polling means to pull off the root of the tree and re-balance the tree after doing so.

A priority queue (PQ) is binary heap. Its graphical representation looks like that of a binary tree. Two properties are import to a priority queue: that it is balanced (Structure Property) and that each node's value is less than (or greater than) that of its children (Heap Order Property).

What's great about a PQ is that the element at its root is the next sorted item you want to access. Its operations allow for re-balancing the PQ and preserving the heap order property after removing the root. Adding a node to the PQ also preserves both properties.

You can add things from your infinite stream to your PQ and after each add add operation, you can be sure the root of the PQ is the smallest (or largest) thing. Keep in mind though, that since the PQ itself isn't sorted, you cannot search it as you would a binary search tree.

Some links:

http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Trees/PriorityQueueswithBinaryHeaps.html
http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/

Just search the internet for Priority Queues; you'll find tons of info.